# "Cancel" is a relevant word in my page because of bootstrap popups

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I am using bootstrap's modals. Each modal contains a button (register, login, etc) and a "**Cancel**" button.

When I first released the website, all popups were in the header (they are hidden, but you know bots will read them).

A few weeks later, I placed them in the footer because I saw on my `Google webmaster tools > Optimization > Content Keywords` that "**Cancel**" was the 2nd most relevant word with a 100% relevancy.

And the first word was the name of the website of course with 100% relevancy as well.

A few weeks later, the word "**Cancel**" dropped to the 3rd position with around 75% relevancy.

Is there a way to fix this? Remove or lower the relevancy of the word "**Cancel**"?

Comment: Does it matter in terms of actual search results? Google probably deals with that type of thing in their algorithm.

Comment: Are you sure? Because "Cancel" is not a stopword

Comment: That report in WMT only shows which keywords are use a lot on the site.  It doesn't mean you will actually be ranked for those keywords. Poor keywords appearing in that report don't mean that you need to take action for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why doesnt you inject the code for the modals in a `$(document).ready` function, by that you will hide the content from searchengines

*2. If your deepest concern is your page relevancy in google, you can instruct google not to index certain parts of your page. Simply use `googleoff / googleon` comments, like this 
    <!--googleoff: index-->
    <div>this will not be indexed by google</div>
    <!--googleon: index>*

documentation :
https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/46/admin_crawl/Preparing#pagepart

---

**UPDATE / CORRECTION** !!!

googleon / googleoff only work with Google Search Appliance, as [Stephen Ostermiller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145388/stephen-ostermiller) points out. Googlebot takes the whole page or nothing. So the solution must be suggestion #1, separate the modals to a file for themselves and inject the content into the footer (or other tag) in a document ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $.get("modals.html", function(html) {
        $("#footer").append(html);
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: googleoff and googleon **only** works for pages indexed via a Google Search Appliance when creating your own search engine.  It has no effect on googlebot when it is crawling for the main Google index.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller, sad to hear it - so I did a wrong answer! Good to be corrected. I didnt knew, have never used those google-comments myself, I just remenbered reading about them long time ago :-(  I correct the answer!

Comment: Your suggestions about inserting via javascript is a good one.